# .write function not writing back to original line after finished

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code doesn't like me asking it to append certain info to specific lines. And I'm not sure why?

For reference, my code looks like this:

```
def lookOnMe(fileName):
import socket
global HostName
with open(fileName, 'r+') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        f.seek(0)
        print(line)
        findStop = line.index("|")
        remainder = line[findStop+2:]
        findStop = remainder.index("|")
        ipAdd = remainder[:findStop]
        ipAdd = "".join(ipAdd.split())
        try:
            HostName = socket.gethostbyaddr(ipAdd)
        except:
            HostName = '-'

        f.write(line.rstrip('\n') + " | " + HostName + '\n')
        f.read()
```

And the input string, like this:

```
5558    | 1.000.00.00      | 1.222.0.0/10        | ER | apnic    | 2001-07-19 | SOMESTUFF
```

Comment: You need a tmp file for that to copy to

Comment: that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple.

You `next(f)` statement reads one line, the first line in the file, and does nothing with it.

Then, you do `for line in f` for the first time, and it tries to read the second line. Which will be empty (because you probably have a newline after the first line).

It fails parsing your empty line with the substring detection, because there are not `|` chars, or anything of that kind.